# Views(Cache enable, pagination enable) page is showing page 1 data after page 1

Tags: views, caching

I am using some caching modules like views_content_cache, cache_actions, entity cache for caching.
I have created a page using views(cache enable) with pagination. The problem is 
when i go after page 1, it shows page 1 data and if i refresh the page its showing correct data. But if i disable the views cache its working perfect.

Can anyone suggest any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't cache the rendered output, only cache the query. If you cache the rendered output then you will have problems with pagers.

Comment: Hey its working for timed based cache, but it does not work for content based cache. Any suggestion ? and how to solve this for rule based cache where ?

Comment: FWIW, I had to disable both render and query caching